# Automatic system for os image creation/recovery

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, backup

I will be doing some laptop cleaning with full disk format and os reinstal of Win7. And I thought about creating sepereate linux partition for os partition image.

I know that It can be easily done with one of system rescue cd's but that would leave me as "maintainer" of whole ordeal and as this cleaning is one time favor I don't think that tere is a way to properly introduce my pal to such idea of backup.

What I thought about is in a way a copy of dreaded oem recovery partitions but using light linux distro with "stupid" simple GUI.

Set a grub for win7, backup-boot and restore-boot and just leave all the magick to scripts, keeping the user interaction only to limited tasks such as deleting older backups when there is no space left for newer. Or ideally even this could be left for scripts.

Clonezilla looks ideal but it looks like it is mainly for live cd/usb usage.

Any thoughts?

best regards,
quert

Answer (score 0):

Not a bad idea — at least not the "recovery partition" OS-reinstall thing. As a backup, though? Having stuff on a separate partition is not a backup for anything other than if the user accidentally deletes a file. Should the hard drive crash and burn it's all gone. It's better to use an external drive, BD-ROM or The Cloud.

As for reading and writing the Windows partition as an image, you'd just need "dd".

Comment: Well, maybe my wording was a bit off. What I meant was that I thought  as it would be disaster remedial tool - virus, os breakage such eventualities. And backup would mean - os partition  image.